# MongoDB aggregate query $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to populate my user field with $lookup and here is my output:

```
 [
   {
     ...
     user: [],
     ...
   }
 ]
```

As you can see, The output is an array and user field is an empty array as well, also I want to make a query, that compare multiple fields. Lets say I have this object:

```
{
   social: {
     facebook: 'facebook.com/asd',
     twitter: 'https://twitter.com/'
   },
   skills: [ 'asd', 'asd', 'html' ],
   _id: 5eec9c9a2d6d1d46e8b05fb4,
   user: {
     _id: 5eec9c752d6d1d46e8b05fb3,
     name: 'Simeon Lazarov',
     avatar: 'uploads\\1592682240020 - background.jpg'
   },
   status: 'Junior Developer',
   experience: [
     {
       current: true,
       _id: 5eef06638af42217d8c5480a,
       title: 'ASD',
       company: 'SAD',
       location: 'ASD',
       from: 2020-06-08T00:00:00.000Z,
       to: null
     }
   ],
   education: [
     {
       current: true,
       _id: 5eef5f0dd06ee324a4a7b1d2,
       school: 'asd',
       degree: 'asd',
       fieldofstudy: 'asd',
       from: 2020-06-24T00:00:00.000Z,
       to: null
     }],
   contacts: [ { _id: 5eee23bd862ab70ba0235a85, user: 5eedffa6062e6231a859433a } ],
   date: 2020-06-19T11:08:10.883Z,
   __v: 1,
   website: 'asd',
   company: 'asd'
 }
```

And want to compare if company, skills(all skills of this object to be contained in others objects) or etc. are equal.

Here is my NOT working code:

```
await Profile.aggregate([{$lookup: {from:"user",localField: "user",
         foreignField: "name", as: "user"}},{$match :{$or:[{"company":{$regex:profile.company}},{"skills":{ $eq: profile.skills}  }]}}]).skip((req.params.page - 1) * 10).limit(11);
```

P.S Sorry for writing so bad, it's my first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just have mismatches in your `$lookup` fields compare to what the schema holds, I rewrote it like this:

```
await Profile.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"company": {$regex: profile.company}},
                {"skills": {$all: profile.skills}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $skip: req.params.page ? req.params.page - 1 : 0 // make sure this can't be -1
    },
    {
        $limit: 11
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$user"
    }
])
```

Notice I moved the `$lookup` to be the last stage as it's the most expensive part of the pipeline and there's no need to do it on the entire collection.

Comment: Hello! First of all thank you for the fast and awesome answer!
I want to match all users that have all the skills from profile.skills and other problem is that user still an empty array, please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: So you want to use `$all` and not `$eq` so users with extra skills are still matched, apart from that the syntax is correct. make sure you save the `user._id` in platforms as ObjectId and not string. otherwise you should either lookup by name (not recommended as users can have the same name) or using `$toObjectId` which is only available for Mongo v4.0+

Comment: Where is the _id that's on the sample you posted?

Comment: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-mendeleev-614ur?file=/src/index.js) Here are my models. I think I'm trying to connect profile with username but I need to do vice versa because my user is main collection

Comment: Just change the `$lookup` like i did. however the schema you posted vs the link don't match.

Comment: the schema I posted is done with `.populate()`. Can you explain me why I get empty array, because I'm expecting object with 3 fields?

Comment: the lookup just expects an `$eq` match. so just make sure `user` on platforms is eq to `_id` on user.

Comment: I check them and they are `$eq` in mongoDB atlas. I dont find any problems that to work but... Thank you for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: And is the collection for sure called `user` and not `users`?

Comment: I changed it to users and now I have an array but I want to be object. It appear like this `users: [ [Object] ]`, but I want to be like this `
user: {
   _id: 5eec9c752d6d1d46e8b05fb3,
   name: Simeon Lazarov,
   avatar: uploads\\1592682240020 - background.jpg
}`

Comment: I added an $unwind stage at the end

Comment: Thank you! Everthing is working now. AWESOME! One last question if is possible. What should I do if I want to add lets say experience[].company to match profile.experience[].company and if there is any matches to return aswell. I would apply this to education aswell.

Comment: the dot notation syntax does not change for arrays so you could do something like `"experience.comapny" :{$in: [ ...companies ...]}`

Comment: I tried `{"experience.company" :{$in: [ profile.experience.company]}}`, but if there is no experience show aswell and here `{"company": {$regex: profile.company}}` if company name is undefined it says $regex has to be a string any suggestions?